# Action with two chained requests. "Cannot read property then of undefined" error

Tags: react-redux, axios, action

Most of my api calls are a function that get called from an action like this

Action:

```
export const fetchSomethingAction = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: types.FETCH_SOMETHING_REQUEST })
    return api.fetchSomething()
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: types.FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESS, data: response.data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: types.FETCH_SOMETHING_FAILURE, error })            
      })
  }
}
```

And the axios request goes something like this:

```
export const fetchSomething = () => {
  return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${api}/endpoint`
  });
}
```

Now I need to make two chained requests, and have the action dispatch an error if **any of the two** requests fails

So how do I chain the request to achieve this?

I was doing for example

```
export const fetchSomething = () => {
      axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${api}/endpoint1`
      })
      .then(res => {
         return fetchSomething2(res.param)
      })
      .catch(err => return err)
    }

const fetchSomething2 = (param) => {
      return axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${api}/endpoint1?param=${param}`
      });
    }
```

But I get `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in the action.

Do I need two actions, one for each function? Is that the proper way to do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetchSomething` function has an arrow function that is defined with braces, but does not have a return statement, and thus implicitly returns undefined. Change it to either not use braces, or have a return statement.

Without braces:

```js
export const fetchSomething = () =>
      axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${api}/endpoint1`
      })
      .then(res => {
         return fetchSomething2(res.param)
      })
      .catch(err => return err)
```

With a return:

```js
export const fetchSomething = () => {
      return axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${api}/endpoint1`
      })
      .then(res => {
         return fetchSomething2(res.param)
      })
      .catch(err => return err)
    }
```

Here's a smaller example you can use to understand the difference:

```js
> a = () => 1; a()
1

> a = () => { 1 }; a()
undefined

> a = () => { return 1 }; a()
1
```

Comment: Thank you. I have to wait 9 hours to award the bounty, so I'll award it then, Thanks again for your detailed response

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find if ESLint had a lint to make this easily detectable, but I didn't really find what I was searching for. [`arrow-body-style`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style) `as-needed` could be good, though